# Do we need to use plugins for modularizing

Tags: hapi.js

Is it mandatory to use plugins for modularizing the code. Can we just create js files and put the handlers and routes in different js files and export them as needed to achieve modularization.

Comment: Yes that will work, plugins just make it easy to encapsulate logic such as authorisation

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are just Hapi's way of modularizing application code.
For instance, in my application i wanted to perform https and www redirections on requests. 
Initially the code looked like this -

```
server.ext({
type: 'onRequest',
method: function (request, reply) {
    if (/^www\./.test(request.headers.host)) {
        return reply()
            .redirect('https' + '://' + request.headers.host.replace(/^www\./, '') + request.url.path)
            .code(301);
    } else {

        reply.continue();
    }

}
});
```

After that I created a plugin [hapi-gate](https://npmjs.com/package/hapi-gate), thinking that other people like me would also have this need. 
Now my code looks like this -

```
server.register({
 register: require('hapi-gate'),
 options: {https: true,
        www: true} // will force https and www on all requests
})
```

You decide now which one looks cleaner and modularized..